# Edit and run a sequence of scripts in a less-manual way [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, automation, automated-tests

I am trying to find a way to edit and run a sequence of python scripts in a less manual way.

For context, I am running a series of simulations, which consist in running three codes in order 10 times, making minor changes to each code every time. The problem I am encountering is that this process leads to easy mistakes and chaotic work.

These are the type of edits I have to make to each code.
- Modify input/output file name
- Change value of a parameter

What is the best practice to deal with this? I imagine that the best idea would be to write another python script that does all this. Is there a way to edit other python codes, from within a code, and run them?

I don't intend or want anyone to write a code for me. I just need to **be pointed in a general direction**. I have searched for ways to 'automatize' codes, but haven't yet been successful in finding a solution to my query (mainly the editing part).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The thing that can change (files or parameter values) should be able to be either passed in or injected. Could be from a command line parameter, configuration file, or method argument. This is the "general direction" I offer.